# JUnit test for tess4J application

Tags: java, junit

I want to test my method to see if it will read the file correctly. I just can't seem to wrap my head around JUnit Testing. Can someone show me how to correctly write a JUnit test for this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs;

public class ImageTest {

    public static String imageService(String filePath) {
        File imageFile = new File("tessImage.png");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();

        //Let tessdata be extracted in case you dont have tessdata folder
        File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata");
        //Set the tessdata path
        instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getAbsolutePath());

        instance.setLanguage("eng");
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            return result;
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return "this is an error" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forword: your exception handling is horrific. Don't return an error message when your caller is expecting the OCR string. Stick to the JAVA style. In case of an error - throw an EXCEPTION!

Next: you never actually use the "filePath" parameter. This is clearly a bug.

You first need to ask yourself WHAT to test. Is it the "imageService" method you want to test? Then create a second class and from there, you would test your method. Within this test class, you would take an example file, call your imageService and compare the result with what you would expect. Those kind of comparisons are done with Assert-statements. Please check the jUnit docs for more detail.